# How do I refresh SignalR connection if connection timeouts from inactivity

Tags: angularjs, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have an angular application using SignalR. When the user is authenticated, I initialize a connection to the server. I believe that if client is inactive after a certain amount of time, it will disconnect. With the code below, how would I reconnect if it disconnects from inactivity?

```
var initializeSockets = function(){
  self.proxy = null;
  var connection = $.hubConnection(ENV.socketEndpoint,{
      qs: {token:User.getToken()},
      logging: false,
      useDefaultPath: false
  });
  self.proxy = connection.createHubProxy('messageCreatedEmitter');
  self.proxy.on('onMessageCreated',function(data){
    //the following is wrapped in a try catch
    //because it will break in a browser, and
    //will not allow the message to be emitted
    try {
      Alert.messageReceived();
    } catch (e) {
    }
    $rootScope.$emit('Messages:messageReceived',data);
  })

  if($.connection.hub && $.connection.hub.state === $.signalR.connectionState.disconnected
    || $.connection.hub.state === undefined){
    connection.start().done(function(){
      $log.info('connected');
    })
  }
}

 $rootScope.$on('User:userAuthenticated',function(event,user){
   initializeSockets();
 })
```

Comment: Are you certain it's disconnecting from inactivity and not automatically reconnecting?

Comment: Well I know it is doing that, but I assumed after a certain amount of time of inactivity it would disconnect. Am I wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure, I know SignalR has a pretty strong fallback/reconnect system... you may want to sent a "ping" message every couple minutes just to make sure the node is alive.  Unless you *want* to disconnect after inactivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could watch for the disconnect and reconnect;

```
$.connection.yourHubName.client.disconnect(function () {
    $.connection.hub.start();
});
```

Comment: I tried this earlier, but it tells me that `$.connection.hub.disconnect(...)` is not a function

Comment: @TheJediCowboy  -you can use $.connection.hub.disconnected(...)    refer this :https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client

Comment: @Stafford Williams please check this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47504489/signalr-not-working-when-system-is-ideal-for-some-time