# SignalR not working when system is ideal for some time

Tags: angularjs, signalr, signalr-hub

```
$.connection.myHubName.client.disconnect(function () {
    $.connection.hub.start();
});
```

on hub.start(); server is started but still it working properly

Comment: For me you question is not clear.

Comment: "is started but still it working properly" << so it's all good? What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The correct method is hanging off the hub connection itself not the hub (so *not* the client object).

`$.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
    console.log('We are currently experiencing difficulties with the connection.')
});`